# $concatArrays only supports arrays, not object

Tags: arrays, mongodb, go, slice, mongo-go

I'm trying to code a perfectly working MongoDB query in Go, but I'm having a hard time with arrays.

Working on JSON:

```
[
...
{
    $project: {
        acl: {
            $reduce: {
                input: "$a.accesses",
                initialValue: [],
                in: {
                    $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

But not working on Go:

```
pipe := mongo.Pipeline{
    ...
    bson.D{{Key: "$project", Value: bson.M{
        "acl": bson.M{
            "$reduce": bson.M{
                "input":        "$a.accesses",
                "initialValue": bson.M{},
                // None of the below works
                "in": bson.M{"$concatArrays": bson.A{"$$value", "$$this"}},
                // "in": bson.M{"$concatArrays": []interface{}{"$$value", "$$this"}},
                // "in": bson.M{"$concatArrays": [2]string{"$$value", "$$this"}},
                // "in": bson.M{"$concatArrays": []string{"$$value", "$$this"}},
                // "in": bson.M{"$concatArrays": []interface{}{"$$value", "$$this"}},
                // "in": bson.D{{Key: "$concatArrays", Value: []interface{}{"$$value", "$$this"}}},
            },
        },
    }}},
}
```

Error: `$concatArrays only supports arrays, not object`

I'm new in Go so I'm quite sure I'm missing the concept of arrays somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Go value you supply for `initialValue` is **not** an array:

```
"initialValue": bson.M{},
```

Instead do:

```
"initialValue": []interface{}{},
```

Or:

```
"initialValue": bson.A{},
```

Comment: OK that worked! I was just looking at the wrong area. Thank you so much!